# How to not show brands that was serviced the last month

Tags: mysql

I have this code where it shows the brands that was serviced last month

```
SELECT t1.Brand, t1.ID,

DATE_FORMAT((t2.Tstamp), "%m/%e/%Y") AS "Last Serviced", 


FROM Table1 t1

INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.Equip_ID

WHERE
MONTH(t2.Tstamp) <> "01"
Group by t1.ID
Order by t2.Tstamp
```

Output of that is

```
Brand  |  ID | Last Serviced
Polo   |  1  | 12/12/2013
Shirt  |  2  | 12/24/2013
```

Then if i do another service on the brand Polo, it will insert a new row for the month of January. What I want to happen is since i did service on Polo then it won't appear on the list anymore, the list should be

```
Brand  |  ID | Last Serviced
Shirt  |  2  | 12/24/2013
```

How do I that? What else do I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want brands where the most recent service date is last month.  For that, use `having`:

```
SELECT t1.Brand, t1.ID, DATE_FORMAT(t2.Tstamp, "%m/%e/%Y") AS "Last Serviced", 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.Equip_ID
Group by t1.ID
having MONTH(max(t2.Tstamp)) <> "01"
Order by t2.Tstamp;
```

I would include the year and month in the comparison, but this follows the logic of your original query.

EDIT:

To include year in the query, base the comparisons on the current date:

```
SELECT t1.Brand, t1.ID, DATE_FORMAT(t2.Tstamp, "%m/%e/%Y") AS "Last Serviced", 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.Equip_ID
Group by t1.ID
having year(max(t2.Tstamp)) <> year(now()) and
       month(max(t2.Tstamp)) <> month(now())
Order by t2.Tstamp;
```

Comment: How can I include the month and year to compare like how you said?

Answer (score 1):

Using **CASE** statements.  Let`s see:

```
SELECT t1.Brand, t1.ID, 
case(when MONTH(t2.Tstamp)=01 then NULL else DATE_FORMAT(t2.Tstamp, "%m/%e/%Y") end ) as `Last Serviced` 
from FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.Equip_ID 
Group by 2 Order by 3
```